# How can I export a List as a featureCollection in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'd like to know how can I export as a featureCollection the List (line 31) of the following script:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5f453a2f3cf39c4be49ac4f4df47ac08

Comment: Thank you! I will try to fix this issue. I thought that these variables ab, cc, var, cn, si, wr should also be taken from squares. Anyway, this is all really great!

Comment: In my **Editing Note** you have a solution.

Comment: Fantastic! My only remaining question, if possible, is why 'var squares = ee.FeatureCollection(list.map(computeSquares)).flatten();' increases the number of elements from 312 to 460.

Comment: I know the answer. Most of the countries have one feature in each feature collection, however,  some of them have 3, 6 or 8 features (i.e. Russia). You can corroborate that with 'size' method of **ee.FeatureCollection**. However, main issue is 'sum'. Values are strange in many case and, I think is a scale issue,

Comment: Thanks, I think it is because of the 'crs' rather than the scale. This map uses Moll as the crs and this seems to be an issue, I think. In case there is any suggestion on this

Comment: It could be 'crs'. Image and country bounds don't coincide. For this reason there are many features with zero population. My suggestion is to use my former approach here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395815/how-to-get-the-right-scale-and-total-value-of-a-world-population-map-using-gee/395853#395853 . It works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that "export" means to Google Drive. In this case, you can add following lines (complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f76f3b1f95642505dddcde003f806edc)) after line 31.

```
// Apply your function to each item in the list by using the map() function => 31 line
var squares = ee.FeatureCollection(list.map(computeSquares)).flatten();

//print(squares);

// Export the FeatureCollection to a SHP file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: squares,
  folder: 'GEE_Folder',
  description:'squares',
  fileFormat: 'SHP'
});

//Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection(squares));
//Map.centerObject(squares);

//--------------end function/map--------
```

It worked for me and in 12 minutes exported to Google Drive about 150 MB of this vector file (squares) as shapefile.

**Editing Note:**

Following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/94e545703a730e67a16b46b447ec2834) also exports fields as CSV.

```
//population
var pop = ee.Image("JRC/GHSL/P2016/POP_GPW_GLOBE_V1/2015");

//Boundaries
var worldcountries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

var list = worldcountries.aggregate_array('country_na');

//print(list);

//------Function/map---------

var computeSquares = function(country) {

  var filterCountry = ee.Filter.inList('country_na',[country]);
  var bound = worldcountries.filter(filterCountry);

  var popcountry = pop.clip(bound);

  var sumpop =popcountry.reduceRegions({
    collection:bound,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    scale:250,
  
   });

  return sumpop;

};

// Apply your function to each item in the list by using the map() function.
var squares = ee.FeatureCollection(list.map(computeSquares)).flatten();

//print(squares);

// Export the FeatureCollection to a SHP file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: squares,
  folder: 'GEE_Folder',
  description:'squares',
  fileFormat: 'SHP'
});

//Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection(squares));
//Map.centerObject(squares);

//abbreviati; country_co; country_na; sum; system:index; and wld_rgn
var ab = squares.aggregate_array('abbreviati');
var cc = squares.aggregate_array('country_co');
var cn = squares.aggregate_array('country_na');
var sum = squares.aggregate_array('sum');
var si = squares.aggregate_array('system:index');
var wr = squares.aggregate_array('wld_rgn');

var count = squares.size();

var seq = ee.List.sequence(0, count.subtract(1));

var fields = seq.map(function(ele) {
  
  var list = ee.List([]);
  
  list = list.add(ab.get(ele))
    .add(cc.get(ele))
    .add(cn.get(ele))
    .add(sum.get(ele))
    .add(si.get(ele))
    .add(wr.get(ele));
  
  return list;
  
});

print("fields", fields);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(fields.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'abbreviati': ee.String(el.get(0)),
    'country_co': ee.String(el.get(1)),
    'country_na': ee.String(el.get(2)),
    'sum': ee.Number(el.get(3)),
    'system:index': ee.String(el.get(4)),
    'wld_rgn': ee.String(el.get(5))
  });
}));

//print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"export_fields", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"fields_CSV",  //file name
"CSV");


//--------------end function/map--------
```

An extract of produced CSV can be observed as follows:

```
system:index,abbreviati,country_co,country_na,sum,wld_rgn,.geo
0_00000000000000000000,,CD,Chad,0.0,Africa,
1_00000000000000000014,Mal.,MI,Malawi,0.0,Africa,
2_00000000000000000015,Zam.,ZA,Zambia,0.0,Africa,
3_00000000000000000016,Zimb.,ZI,Zimbabwe,0.0,Africa,
4_00000000000000000017,Bots.,BC,Botswana,0.0,Africa,
5_00000000000000000018,Nam.,WA,Namibia,0.0,Africa,
6_00000000000000000019,Ang.,AO,Angola,0.0,Africa,
7_0000000000000000001a,Buru.,BY,Burundi,0.0,Africa,
8_0000000000000000001b,Rw.,RW,Rwanda,0.0,Africa,
9_0000000000000000001c,S. Afr.,SF,South Africa,0.0,Africa,
10_0000000000000000001d,Leso.,LT,Lesotho,0.0,Africa,
11_0000000000000000001e,Swaz.,WZ,Swaziland,0.0,Africa,
12_00000000000000000022,May.,MF,Mayotte,0.0,Africa,
13_00000000000000000094,,NG,Niger,0.0,Africa,
14_00000000000000000095,,SU,Sudan,0.0,Africa,
15_00000000000000000096,,LY,Libya,0.0,Africa,
16_00000000000000000097,,UU,Koualou Area,0.0,Africa,
17_00000000000000000098,Tun.,TS,Tunisia,0.0,Africa,
18_000000000000000000a8,,EG,Egypt,0.0,Africa,
19_000000000000000000a9,,EG,Bir Tawil,0.0,Africa,
20_000000000000000000aa,,SU,Halaib Triangle,0.0,Africa,
21_000000000000000000c0,Erit.,ER,Eritrea,0.0,Africa,
22_000000000000000000c1,Eth.,ET,Ethiopia,0.0,Africa,
23_000000000000000000c2,Dji.,DJ,Djibouti,0.0,Africa,
24_000000000000000000c3,Som.,SO,Somalia,0.0,Africa,
25_000000000000000000c4,S. Sudan,OD,South Sudan,0.0,Africa,
26_000000000000000000c5,,UU,Abyei Area,0.0,Africa,
27_000000000000000000c6,,KE,Kenya,0.0,Africa,
28_000000000000000000c7,Ug.,UG,Uganda,0.0,Africa,
29_000000000000000000c8,Tanz.,TZ,Tanzania,0.0,Africa,
30_000000000000000000c9,Moz.,MZ,Mozambique,0.0,Africa,
31_000000000000000000ca,Como.,CN,Comoros,0.0,Africa,
32_000000000000000000cb,Madag.,MA,Madagascar,0.0,Africa,
33_000000000000000000dc,C. Ver.,CV,Cabo Verde,0.0,Africa,
34_000000000000000000de,W. Sah.,WI,Western Sahara,0.0,Africa,
35_000000000000000000df,Maur.,MR,Mauritania,0.0,Africa,
36_000000000000000000e0,Mor.,MO,Morocco,0.0,Africa,
37_000000000000000000e1,Sp.,SP,Spain (Canary Is),0.0,Africa,
38_000000000000000000e2,Port.,PO,Portugal (Madeira Is),0.0,Africa,
39_000000000000000000e4,Sp.,SP,Spain (Africa),0.0,Africa,
40_000000000000000000e8,Alg.,AG,Algeria,0.0,Africa,
41_000000000000000000e9,,ML,Mali,0.0,Africa,
42_000000000000000000ea,Burk.,UV,Burkina Faso,0.0,Africa,
43_000000000000000000eb,,TO,Togo,0.0,Africa,
44_000000000000000000ec,,GH,Ghana,0.0,Africa,
45_000000000000000000ed,C. d Iv.,IV,Cote d'Ivoire,0.0,Africa,
46_000000000000000000ee,Gui.,GV,Guinea,0.0,Africa,
47_000000000000000000ef,Sen.,SG,Senegal,0.0,Africa,
48_000000000000000000f0,Gam.,GA,"Gambia, The",0.0,Africa,
49_000000000000000000f1,Gui.-Bis.,PU,Guinea-Bissau,0.0,Africa,
50_000000000000000000f2,S. Leo.,SL,Sierra Leone,0.0,Africa,
51_000000000000000000f3,Liber.,LI,Liberia,0.0,Africa,
52_000000000000000000f4,,BN,Benin,0.0,Africa,
53_000000000000000000f5,Nig.,NI,Nigeria,0.0,Africa,
54_000000000000000000f6,Camer.,CM,Cameroon,0.0,Africa,
55_000000000000000000f7,Equa. Gui.,EK,Equatorial Guinea,0.0,Africa,
56_000000000000000000f8,S. To. & Prin.,TP,Sao Tome & Principe,0.0,Africa,
57_000000000000000000f9,,GB,Gabon,0.0,Africa,
58_000000000000000000fa,Rep. of the Congo,CF,Rep of the Congo,0.0,Africa,
59_000000000000000000fb,Cen. Afr. Rep.,CT,Central African Rep,0.0,Africa,
60_000000000000000000fc,Dem. Rep. of the Congo,CG,Dem Rep of the Congo,0.0,Africa,
61_0000000000000000003e,H.K.,HK,Hong Kong,0.0,E Asia,
62_0000000000000000003f,,MC,Macau,0.0,E Asia,
63_00000000000000000040,Tai.,TW,Taiwan,0.0,E Asia,
64_00000000000000000041,,UU,Senkakus,0.0,E Asia,
65_00000000000000000042,,JA,Japan,1.2367127457851154E8,E Asia,
66_00000000000000000043,S. Kor.,KS,"Korea, South",0.0,E Asia,
67_00000000000000000044,N. Kor.,KN,"Korea, North",0.0,E Asia,
68_00000000000000000045,,UU,Korean Is. (UN Jurisdiction),0.0,E Asia,
69_00000000000000000046,,CH,China,4.13626724095709E8,E Asia,
69_00000000000000000048,,CH,China,1.5496324354785228E7,E Asia,
69_000000000000000000d5,,CH,China,6541.133977252492,E Asia,
69_000000000000000000d9,,CH,China,113014.24493963121,E Asia,
70_00000000000000000046,,CH,China,4.13626724095709E8,E Asia,
70_00000000000000000048,,CH,China,1.5496324354785228E7,E Asia,
70_000000000000000000d5,,CH,China,6541.133977252492,E Asia,
70_000000000000000000d9,,CH,China,113014.24493963121,E Asia,
71_00000000000000000046,,CH,China,4.13626724095709E8,E Asia,
71_00000000000000000048,,CH,China,1.5496324354785228E7,E Asia,
71_000000000000000000d5,,CH,China,6541.133977252492,E Asia,
71_000000000000000000d9,,CH,China,113014.24493963121,E Asia,
72_00000000000000000046,,CH,China,4.13626724095709E8,E Asia,
72_00000000000000000048,,CH,China,1.5496324354785228E7,E Asia,
72_000000000000000000d5,,CH,China,6541.133977252492,E Asia,
72_000000000000000000d9,,CH,China,113014.24493963121,E Asia,
73_00000000000000000129,,UU,Liancourt Rocks,0.0,E Asia,
74_0000000000000000000a,Rus.,RS,Russia,1.021918526464285E8,Europe,
74_00000000000000000011,Rus.,RS,Russia,5249239.941191522,Europe,
74_0000000000000000000f,Rus.,RS,Russia,2.6806786216873176E7,N Asia,
74_00000000000000000010,Rus.,RS,Russia,2725952.8460667613,N Asia,
74_00000000000000000122,Rus.,RS,Russia,1057696.7556383794,N Asia,
74_00000000000000000128,Rus.,RS,Russia,4781155.418985548,N Asia,
75_0000000000000000000c,Ukr.,UP,Ukraine,0.0,Europe,
76_0000000000000000000d,Rom.,RO,Romania,0.0,Europe,
77_0000000000000000000e,Mol.,MD,Moldova,0.0,Europe,
78_0000000000000000000a,Rus.,RS,Russia,1.021918526464285E8,Europe,
78_00000000000000000011,Rus.,RS,Russia,5249239.941191522,Europe,
78_0000000000000000000f,Rus.,RS,Russia,2.6806786216873176E7,N Asia,
78_00000000000000000010,Rus.,RS,Russia,2725952.8460667613,N Asia,
78_00000000000000000122,Rus.,RS,Russia,1057696.7556383794,N Asia,
78_00000000000000000128,Rus.,RS,Russia,4781155.418985548,N Asia,
79_00000000000000000012,Fin.,FI,Finland,5410341.968123293,Europe,
80_00000000000000000013,Nor.,NO,Norway,4835198.770938944,Europe,
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to export 'squares' as a '.csv' file containing the following six fields:  abbreviati; country_co; country_na; sum; system:index; and wld_rgn?

Comment: If they are properties of these feature collection it is possible, I will see in only one feature for developing corresponding function for extracting them.

Comment: Is there a way to do this wothout using "flatten()"? Flatten repeats some Feature.Collection over estimating the total value. For example values for China, Russia, etc are double counted. As one can see, the number of feature collections increased from 312 to 460 using flatten. Thanks.